# Restrictions of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})$ to $\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}$ are exactly $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

In the book of Harald Niederreiter : Algebraic geometry in Coding theory, we get that
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})=\{\sigma|_{\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}} :\ \sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})\}.
$$
as a corollary of the theorem stating that we have an isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Gal}\left(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}} / \mathbb{F}_{q}\right) \simeq \lim _{\leftarrow} \operatorname{Gal}\left(\mathbb{F}_{q^{i}} / \mathbb{F}_{q}\right) .
$$
The isomorphism is $$
\theta:\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})\rightarrow\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^{i}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})\ .
$$ where the i-th coordinnate of $\theta(\sigma)$ is the resriction of $\sigma$ to $\mathbb{F}_{q^{i}}$.

The inclusion $$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})\supset\{\sigma|_{\mathbb{F}_{q^{m}}} :\ \sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})\}.
$$ is okey.
But I cant see how every automorphism of $\operatorname{Gal}\left(\mathbb{F}_{q^{i}} / \mathbb{F}_{q}\right)$ is the restriction of an aumorphism of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}/\mathbb{F}_{q})$ as a consequence of the isomorphism.

Comment: Probably needs a call to Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @Lubin could you give more informations ?

Comment: Well, the algebraic closure of $k=\Bbb F_q$ is union (direct limit) of finite extensions of your field $K=\Bbb F_{q^m}$, and on each of these finite extensions, you may extend your given automorphism (by making a choice, since there will be finitely many such). You’ll need to use AC to patch these various extensions of the autom together in a consistent way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from pretty standard results in Galois theory.  If $k$ is a field with separable closure $k^{\textrm{sep}}$ (which is the same as the algebraic closure in the case where $k$ is perfect, e.g. a finite field), and $L$ is a Galois extension of $k$ contained in $k^{\textrm{sep}}$, then every $k$-automorphism of $L$ extends (nonuniquely) to a $k$-automorphism of $k^{\textrm{sep}}$.  Conversely, every $k$-automorphism of $k^{\textrm{sep}}$ restricts to a $k$-automorphism of $L$.  In other words,

$$\operatorname{Gal}(L/k) = \{ \sigma|_L : \sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(k^{\textrm{sep}}/k) \}. $$

Comment: could you please suggest a book or a course where i can find this result!!

Comment: Check out Hungerford's graduate algebra book

Comment: thank youuu !!!